# Will using log in screen command capture passwords?

Tags: linux, security, passwords

According to [this tutorial](http://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) running `Ctrl-a H` in a screen session creates a running log. In general this sounds great, it seems useful to log everything I type or that is printed to output, with the exception of passwords, which are obviously sensitive. Does screen correctly exclude these?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Screen will only record what is output to the window. I tested and the file did not contain password characters.

See the actual logfile contents here: http://paste.pound-python.org/show/CXP2ppd2wKoMWFmlPsFU/